# Import image while importing products in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image-upload

Is it possible to import images while importing the product ?

I've never done a large import on Magento before but i'm moving my store from wordpress to magento. In wordpress you can enter a web address for the image and it will find it and import it, and display it on the product page.

Is it possible to do that in Magento?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Dave it is possible, I strongly recommend reading a blog post about doing it in Magento 1 here https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/05/importing-product-images-via-csv-in-magento-1-7-0-0/ . If you have a lot of photos to upload it is also possible to loop through in a scripting language like python and build a CSV that way instead. Best of luck. If you have questions on how to Format it, the [Magento 2 documentation](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html) explains quite well even though it's for Magento 1 as I think CSV uploads remain the same.

Comment: That blog post is from 2012. I take it it's still relevant ?. I'm moving my stores over to magento. I know little about it so it's all learning.  Thanks for your reply. I'm not using Magento 2. it's Magento 1.9

Comment: I would imagine it's still relevant, what's changed in the recent years has mostly been in Magento 2, which as you state you're not dealing with, i'm also learning too so i could be wrong but let me know if adding the relevant columns works for you